# Cannot see any connection in Metadata Explorer

Tags: vora

I've created several connections in the "Connection Manager" application in SAP Data Hub 2.5, but none of these applications are listed for browsing in the "Metadata Explorer".

Am I missing some additional configuration steps?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to set connection parameter 'Manage Metadata' to 'true'. This parameter can be changed in the Connection app either when creating the connection or when editing it.

[image]